# Is it possible to include an additional navigation property on a nested hierarchical type in Entity Framework?

Tags: c#, entity-framework

Even my question title is a bit of a mouthful, but what I'm trying to do is avoid additional round trips to the database. What I want to achieve is this using Entity Framework 6 (or later if there is one).

If I have an entity that has a property of a collection of hierarchical entities but in *one* case, one of the types of inherited type entities I want to expand an additional navigation property (that is also a collection) is this possible?

To expand a navigation property you use the 'Include' keyword with the property specified, but how does that work with base class type with inherited entities?

e.g. Pseudo code thinking

```
Context.ParentType
   .Include(pt => pt.SubCollection)
   .Include(pt => pt.SubCollection.OfType<SpecialSubType>().SpecialProperty)
```

or something?

So the outcome of this would be that my parent type would have the sub collection entirely materialised in the query, but as part of that the specialised sub collection (that has multiple other types) also brings in the SpecialtyProperty navigation for that one specified sub-type.